# Create advance mouseover shape with inset shadow, with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have tried creating this [mouse over shadow](http://i.solidfiles.net/9272482800.png) for my head menu, but unfortunately I'm not able to create something satisfying enough. I'm playing around with box-radius and box-shadow (inset) in order to create the right shape and shadow.

This is what I got:

```
background: tomato;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 45px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 45px;

-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Can I use some other commands or maybe, I'm forced to use images? In that case, is it possible to use CSS sprites to dynamically change the width with the same image, depending on the length of the text? I have seen sprite images for this purpose, looking something like this [CSS sprite images example](http://i.solidfiles.net/c667e9dcad.png) but I have never used this technique my self since I have failed to find a "how to" guide for it. Maybe you can link me something good or explain this carefully?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Eh, I got the answer from someone, but now he removed his post before I got the chance to try the solution in real life? What to do? Can I, somehow, show deleted posts?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this technique, and just have a red background behind the elements? (and put the indent on top)

http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LawCb

(The javascript there is just to provide demo clicking)
(I have not made that code, just know it.)

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="current" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:15px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  font-size:0;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:1rem;
  color:white;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

li:before,
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:100%;
  width:calc(50% - 12px); /* allows to width of triangle*/
  height:12px;
  background-color: red;
}

li:before{
  left:0;
}

li:after {
  right:0;
}

a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  z-index:-1; /* hide behind link */
  border:12px solid red;
  top:100%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%); /* center the pseudo element and only show bottom half*/
}

a.current:before {
    border-bottom-color:transparent; /* our triangle */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, but I have to say, I'm not sure how this solves my problem? My goal is to create a "custom shape" with shadow on the inside, looking like the first picture I'm linking. If that isn't possible, I need to use images and then there is a new question - how do I do it in the best possible way.

Comment: In your image ( http://i.solidfiles.net/9272482800.png ) I saw no shadow, except the red line on top with that triangle. The above code can help you solve that without anything other than css. What shadow are you referring to?